# DailyRollingFileAppender writes also on SystemOut.log

Tags: logging, log4j, websphere

My application uses log4j for Logging and it's deployed in WebSphere Application Server V7. Log4j jars are included in `WEB-INF/lib`, and the `log4j.properties` file is located externally and loaded throgh `org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer`. Currently, the Log configuration is the following:

```
log4j.logger.com.myapp=DEBUG, InfoAppender, DebugAppender

log4j.appender.InfoAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.File=/home/infoFile.log
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.appender.DebugAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.File=/home/debugFile.log
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

Logging works as expected and the files `infoFile.log` and `debugFile.log` are populated correctly. But also, all the lines that are sent to these files are also written in `SystemOut.log` file on the server, with many other messages from the runtime.

We have many WAR files with this configuration, so the `SystemOut.log` file is getting pretty big very soon, and its getting hard to find logs related to the runtime environment. Is there a way to exclude the messages that are written to `infoFile.log` and `debugFile.log` from `SystemOut.log`?

Comment: To make sure nothing interferes with your logging configuration, could you give log4j.properties some other name?

Comment: It has other name, I used it to simplify the example

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that behavior. I've seen the log4j logging go to WebSphere SystemOut.log *instead of* to my log files, but not *in addition to*. And we use much the same setup you describe. log4j.jar in WEB-INF/lib, log4j.properties in WEB-INF/classes in our case, and DailyRollingFileAppender. And we're not using that Spring configurer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid propagation to `SystemOut.log`, it was only needed to set the **additivity** property of the logger to false. To accomplish that, we added this line to `log4j.properties`.

```
log4j.additivity.com.myapp=false
```