# Additivity in java.util.logging

Tags: logging, java.util.logging

As posted in this question [DailyRollingFileAppender writes also on SystemOut.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846949/dailyrollingfileappender-writes-also-on-systemout-log), we avoid Log propagation from child to parent loggers in `log4j` using the **additivity** property.

I have some components that instead of using log4j are logging using `java.util.logging`, and we have the same issue as with log4j that logs are propagated to `SystemOut.log`. So, is there an equivalent of the **additivity** attribute of log4j in java.util.logging, to avoid log propagation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the equivalent is useParentHandlers

in your config, have something like:

```
your.logger.name.useParentHandlers=false
```

should do the trick

(I haven't used JUL before, that's what I found from Google)